# Can Heroku's cleardb ignite be used for production?

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I understand that there are limitations with regards number of connections etc. but it doesn't have a tick next to "Production Ready"

What does this mean? I cannot use it for production?

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much documentation on this. It's a play to get you paying by suggesting that general performance will be subpar until you do. Which is nonetheless probably very true. Based on performance I've had with Ignite in the past, I certainly wouldn't want to have more than a few people connecting at a given time. Plus, you'll almost certainly tap out of the allowed 5mb of storage very quickly if you're doing anything resource intensive anyway.